Postgres hot standby has a negative replication delay
I am trying to calculate the replication delay of a hot standby in Postgres. I am using the following calculation:
SELECT pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_last_wal_receive_lsn(), pg_last_wal_replay_lsn()) AS replication_delay_bytes;

When I run this, I sometimes see a negative value returned. I found a DataDog blog post that wraps the calculation in abs(), but the blog doesn't go into details of why the abs() is necessary.
There must be something semi-obvious that I am not understanding in this situation.

My guess is that these functions reflect the current state. They are called one after the other, and replication could have proceeded in the meantime. If that is the case, the abs() is just nonsense. If anything, I'd use greatest(pg_wal_lsn_diff(..., ...), 0).

@LaurenzAlbe thanks for your input. Does Postgres guarantee function call order in a situation like this? For instance, will Postgres always run pg_last_wal_receive_lsn() first?
Secondly, would it be better to convert this query to a plpgsql query where I can collect the replay LSN first, and then get the receive LSN? I can guarantee a positive value, I think, with that approach.

I think that PostgreSQL will always call the first function first (but I didn't check the code). The idea with PL/pgSQL code is a good one. That way, you can also verify if my suspicion is true. If you ever get a negative value that way, I was wrong.

Regarding the negative value, might be pg_wal_lsn_diff(...) and pg_lsn_mi(...) can explain.

For anyone in the future that comes across this question, we ended up going with wrapping pg_wal_lsn_diff in a greatest(0, ...). The logic behind this decision was that if you are replaying WAL so fast that you end up with a negative value in the calculation, your replication delay is essentially 0. I think doing the PL/pgSQL variant previously discussed could also be considered a good way to solve this issue.
